# u16string and char16_t in Android NDK

Tags: android, unicode, c++11, android-ndk, utf-16

I wish to create (`std::getline()`) and manipulate UTF-16 strings in the Android NDK, so that I can pass them (relatively) painlessly back to Java for display. Currently, I'm using C++0x, using the `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++0x` switch, which works (I'm using some other 0x functions). Seems the compiler can't find `u16string`. I've included `<string>`, and get no other errors. I wish to do something such as:

```
ifstream file(fileName);
if(!file.is_open()) {
    return false;
}
while(!file.eof()) {
    u16string fileLine;
    std::getline(file, fileLine);

    // Do stuff with fileLine
}
return true;
```

Does the NDK include an out-of-date version of GCC or something? What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NDK does not (at least not officially) support wide characters, UTF-16 or anything like that. Nor does it provide a proper C++ library.

Comment: I'm told the NDK uses GCC, which, when in C++0x mode, natively supports UTF-16. I guess I'm hoping there's some preprocessor-fu or something that can be done for it to recognise `string`s the full C++0x way when in that (officially experimental) mode

Comment: @Warpspace the NDK (at least my aged NDK 4b) comes with gcc-4.4.0, which should indeed support the new C++0x character types char16_t and char32_t - but there is no library support for it. The Android NDK does not even know std::string. The easiest thing would probably be to use UTF-8 - JNI supports both ways. Otherwise, you could use the stlport (no C++0x support) to provide you with std::string or std::basic_string, define/implement char_traits for char16_t and define your own u16string as basic_string<char16_t>. Not sure if stlport supports wchar_t/wstring.

Comment: @Warpspace You can also try inoffical (non-Google) NDK builds, e.g. CrystaX. See http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r4.php. They claim to be fully compatible to the official NDK and added full C++, RTTI and exception support.

Comment: Had a look at both of those. I managed to get access to the C++0x features of GCC 4.4.0, but you're right, no UTF-16 (library) `string`s. JNI doesn't respect UTF-8 properly, as it has to be "Modified UTF-8", which is different. I wrote my own code to read in UTF-16 (little endian) strings as (proper) UTF-8, and then converted the double-bytes (words) to UTF-16. Not the prettiest solution, but decent and robuste (as much as C-style strings are, which is what I eventually used). Can post the code if anyone is interested.

Comment: So whats the solution here.  I am on NDK R7 and latest Cyrstax and I don't see any support for comparisons like wcsicmp, wcscasecmp?