# How to Convert wchar wstring in C++ to something better supported?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am a Java developer, and I have run into compiling problems with Android NDK compiling C++ classes that have wchar and  wstring etc.  After checking if anything might support these, my findings so far indicates that nothing fully supports these on NDK.  This means I need to change them in the source.  How exactly can this be done?  Thanks

Comment: related, not answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385643/solution-for-missing-stdwstring-support-in-android-ndk

Comment: possible duplicate of [u16string and char16_t in Android NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564780/u16string-and-char16-t-in-android-ndk)

Comment: BTW, is there a logic behind not supporting these in the NDK tools?

Comment: @Androider: Google is trailing C++ development by about 15 years. They just got RTTI; expect lambda's somewhere around 2026.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to re-write as much as possible in Java :)

But wchar and friends are basically just "zero-terminated arrays that have 16-bit instead of 8-bit characters".  Microsoft libraries just punt by having parallel versions of strcpy()/wstrcpy(), strlen()/wstrlen(), etc.  It should be fairly straightforward to identify where wchar's are being used, and implement those few simple functions you might need yourself, shouldn't it?

Comment: well yes, but the thing is that C/C++ is the most widely supported language so if you have a nice library in C/C++ you don't have to rewrite for iPhone bada etc.

Comment: Also almost every fast technical library was written in C++. Not that its better than java but its already there from when java was slower than c++.

Comment: Just look at all the C++ library for graphics etc. All in C++

Comment: Your right about adding my own versions though.  Looking to add C++ versions now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, besides flagging the duplicate, I found this interesting article:

TL;DR **We elected to extract the core wide/narrow conversion routines from the Android implementation of JNI in the Android open source project so the conversion runs entirely in native code**

> ### Wide and Narrow Character String Conversions
>
> This is quite a complex issue when  porting an application because of the multiple methods and standards in existence.  Windows Mobile (Windows CE) standardized on the two byte per character unit UTF-16 and with rare exception, the ANSI or one byte per character unit native APIs were eliminated.  The C# language and .NET Compact Framework also utilize UTF-16.
>
> The Linux and Android native API’s rely on single byte per character unit, null terminated strings.  A wide C++ character on Linux is 4 bytes per character as opposed to 2 bytes per character unit on a Microsoft platform.  One effect is to double the length of all wide character strings including string literals preceded by the L character.
>
> One possibility is to translate UTF-16 including surrogate pairs to UTF-8 multi-byte strings which can require one to four bytes for each character, and can contain embedded zero bytes.  The Java Native Interface (JNI) provides routines to translate Java UTF-16 into “Modified” UTF-8.  The modifications result in a narrow character string containing no embedded zeros, only the zero at the end of the string.  Another modification is to translate a four byte UTF-16 surrogate pair into two UTF-8 characters, each three bytes long instead of a single UTF-8 character, four bytes long.
>
> The end result of using JNI routines to translate between wide and narrow strings is that the wide UTF-16 string format is compatible both with Java and Windows Mobile (CE) and the narrow Modified UTF-8 string is compatible with Android / Linux OS API and C run time library.
>
> he Android C run time library (Bionic) contains a wchar.h to implement functions such as wcslen, wcscpy, etc., but as noted in the comments in the header, no actual wide char functions are implemented in the Android C run time library.  We resolve this by using the GNU C++ compiler option “-fshort-wchar” which forces the compiler to treat wide characters as two bytes instead of four bytes.  This makes the L”string” literal two bytes per character and compatible with UTF-16.  We have extracted the actual wide character run time library from the Wine open source project.
>
> It is possible to use JNI as delivered in Android to translate between native C++ wide and narrow strings.  This involves a round trip through the Java environment and thus is not very efficient.  **We elected to extract the core wide/narrow conversion routines from the Android implementation of JNI in the Android open source project so the conversion runs entirely in native code**.

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of a toolchain is to handle this type of issue.

Comment: @Androider: you didn't ask for my opinion, you asked about tools and facts :)

Comment: ok.  well there are not too many calls to these methods so maybe I will just put the C++ methods in the same file that uses them.